# Xcode Switching back to the code editor after a segfault

Tags: xcode

I am not sure if I can ask this question here but it has been is there any way I can go back to the editor window after I encounter an error.

Say there is a segmentation fault, Xcode switches open another file like algorithm. I might get some useful information but I want to go back to the file where the error occurred. Is there a keyboard shortcut that I can go back to my previous active file that I was editing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you set a hotkey for `Go Back (Navigate Menu)` this should do what you want